# An error occurred while the batch was being executed

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to add a foreign key to my database table, but I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
>
> Possible data issues
>   The column [dbo].[Transactions].[Expenses_Id] on table [dbo].[Transactions] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option.
>
> Warnings
>   The column [dbo].[Transactions].[Expenses_Id] on table [dbo].[Transactions] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option.

But my other table (the one I am referring to using the FK) is not empty, so there should not be any null exceptions.

Comment: Are you attempting to add new column `Expenses_Id` and make if refer some other table?

Comment: Yes, I am adding a new Foreign key(Expenses_Id) in Transactions table, which refers to Id in the table Expenses @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to add new column which does not allow NULLs. Since there are some rows already, what value should be in every row right after column creation? That is `NULL` or `default` if defined.

Create it with allowed NULLs, update to real values, alter to disable NULLs.